# Value of pressure gradient in a static fluid

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

How can we prove that the value of Pressure Gradient in the horizontal direction represented by $\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}=-dg$ ; { $z$ direction is vertically upwards and $d$ is the density of fluid and $g$ is gravity }.

Comment: Did you try googling it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium

Comment: @ROIMaison that are article does not explains how this equation is derived.

Comment: I think it does. It says **Derivation from force summation**. It also shows the derivation from the Navier Stokes, which leads to the exact equation you're asking, although this derivation is not as explicit.